# grpc java - iterate Context.keyValueEntries?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm newbie of grpc, and developing our server side grpc code.

The ultimate goal is to 'pass **all** variables that matching a specific pattern in
metadata to sub calls'.

The first step is to **get** these key values.

Now I can get any fixed(known at compile time) key value pair:

1. Create a `ServerInterceptor`:

   ```java
   public class HeaderInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor{
     private static final String KEY_KNOWN = "AT_COMPILE_TIME";
     private static final Metadata.Key<String> METADATA_KEY = 
         Metadata.Key.of(KEY_KNOWN, Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
     public static final Context.Key<String> CONTEXT_KEY = 
         Context.key(KEY_KNOWN);

     @Override
     public <REQT, RESPT> Listener<REQT> interceptCall(
         ServerCall<REQT, RESPT> call, 
         Metadata metadata,
         ServerCallHandler<REQT, RESPT> next) {
             Context context = Context.current().withValue(
                 CONTEXT_KEY, 
                 metadata.get(METADATA_KEY));
        //...some other code
       }
   }
   ```
2. In other code:

```java
        import static some.package.HeaderInterceptor.CONTEXT_KEY;
        String value = CONTEXT_KEY.get();
```

But the requirement is more generic, and the key name are unknown until runtime.

In `ServerInterceptor`
`for (String key : metadata.keys())` can iterate all keys and values.

But what is generic version of `SOME_GENERIC_KEY.get()`? I tried `Context.current().keyValueEntries` but cannot compile(not public).

I've searched and read [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145878/how-to-intercept-the-headers-from-in-call-to-one-service-and-insert-it-to-anothe)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502295/how-do-i-grab-variables-from-the-context-scope-while-inside-an-onnext-call-jav)
[3](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7024)

But none of them provides a solution(to this question).

Could anyone help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what is generic version of SOME_GENERIC_KEY.get()? I tried Context.current().keyValueEntries but cannot compile(not public).

`Context` purposefully does not allow iterating over the keys, as this allows using Java visibility to restrict access to setting/getting particular keys. This produces similar results to `ThreadLocal`. Keys use the Java-default identity equality (`k1 == k2`), and the string passed to `Context.key(KEY_KNOWN)` is a *debug* string unused during `get()`s.

While Context is a Map-like data structure, it isn't intended as a general-purpose map as it is immutable and storing many related keys is better served with a normal HashMap or POJO.

Then how do you store many keys, one for each header that  you found in Metadata? Use a Map. Create a Map with the entries found and store *that map* in a `Context.Key<Map<String,String>>` key.

Comment: but I need all the key/value pairs... why can't I iterate them?  How do I know all the headers that the user passed?  This seems overly restrictive and unnecessary.

Comment: @TrevorHickey, headers are stored in Metadata, not Context.